# Twin paradox on hypertorus

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

I will not describe the twin paradox  again. But let's suppose we have two twins, one stationary and the other moving with uniform velocity $c/2$ for instance. And let's suppose that they live in a hypertorus space, which is topological equivalent to an flat plane, so no curvature.
But the hypertorus is a finite space, it means the moving twin will meet again at an instant $t$ in time in the future. What will be their age when they cross each other again?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196267/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic : but any of the answers is exact ; too late for the mine ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in [Time, Topology and the Twin Paradox](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5847) by J.-P. Luminet

> The twin paradox is the best known thought experiment associated with
>   Einstein's theory of relativity. An astronaut who makes a journey into
>   space in a high-speed rocket will return home to find he has aged less
>   than a twin who stayed on Earth. This result appears puzzling, since
>   the situation seems symmetrical, as the homebody twin can be
>   considered to have done the travelling with respect to the traveller.
>   Hence it is called a "paradox". In fact, there is no contradiction and
>   the apparent paradox has a simple resolution in Special Relativity
>   with infinite flat space. In General Relativity (dealing with
>   gravitational fields and curved space-time), or in a compact space
>   such as the hypersphere or a multiply connected finite space, the
>   paradox is more complicated, but its resolution provides new insights
>   about the structure of spacetime and the limitations of the
>   equivalence between inertial reference frames.

The inertial frames for the twins are not symmetric.

> In Special Relativity theory, two reference frames are equivalent if
>   there is a Lorentz transformation from one to the other. The set of
>   all Lorentz transformations is called the Poincaré group – a ten
>   dimensional group which combines translations and homogeneous Lorentz
>   transformations called “boosts”. **The loss of equivalence between
>   inertial frames is due to the fact that a multiply connected spatial
>   topology globally breaks the Poincaré group**.

In a *multiply connected spatial topology*, there are more than one straight path to join 2 points.